# PDF show off (preview)

Tags: php, pdf, preview

I have a customer that do a little wrap up of what happend during the weekend and prep a file in MS Word with pictures and text

that word document is then converted in pdf for downloading on the web site as link. I can make a php script that will check in the folder how many file there is ans make a list of them, but i like to be able to have a preview of the file (automatically) or best a way to view the file online WITHOUT having to download...

Any idea how to do that, how do YOU handle that situation ?

thanks in advance

---

here is a interesting [link](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/da120a6b6e3dcd2a?pli=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried: [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer); it can point to a file on your server

Answer (score 0):

There are few options:
in linux/nix there tools that can convert your pdf file pages to multiple image file.
u can display the image as snapshot to your pdf pages. this  u need some simple skill 
a pgm that do the pdf to image/png/jpeg and some web scripting to display it page by page.

adobe flex can do the tricks. but first of all u need to convert your pdf to swf files.
there few tools that can do that. after that by using flex u can open your swf movie and the paging will be your swf frame.

this is my prototype by using [flex](http://ihsan.com/adzmely/_dp/demo4.html) ... somehow similar to a well known tool in the net...

u can do it also by using image magic tool name convert:
eg:

```
# convert -thumbnail x360 pdffile[0] thumb_0.jpg
```

[pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) ...a nice tool than can generate to html

good luck...

Comment: anything jquery ?.. and when you tell "there few tools that can do that." can you get me the NAME and the LINK to see that tool... thanks

Comment: my prototype i m using flex with this tools http://www.swftools.org/

u can try to search for pdf2jpg etc

Comment: with image magic u have a tool name convert by using convert u can grab an image snapshot of any page in your pdf

Comment: jquery... calling a pdf viewer on client side is possible.. but i think you will have some cross browser issues. u dont need j query for that. i think if u just want to show 1 or 2 pages the image magic tool convert can help u...eg in nix shell: convert -thumbnail x360 $docs_converted_pdffile[0] $docs_path.thumb.jpg  . the cmd will create a jpg file of the pdf first page.